# Changing from v5 to v6, how to make it work with relative paths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My application has scenarios where we need several routes to "pass" through a component to only then render the specifics, not only that but also situations where something is shown for the "parent" route and then split for the children...

It is *imperative* to note that we don't have a single "route config" file, and instead our routes are where we need them.

This was possible with v5, but I am very confused about how to get this accomplished with the new version.

So, currently we have stuff such as:

App.js

```
function App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={['/', '/2', '/more-info']} component={Login} />
      <Route path="/(main|settings|notifications)" component={AuthenticatedUser} />
      <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

AuthenticatedUser.js

```
function AuthenticatedUser= () => {
  {... lots of common code}
  return (
    <div>
      {...common html}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/main" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        <Route path="/notifications" component={Notifications} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Settings.js

```
function Settings= () => {
  {... lots of common code}
  return (
    <div>
      {...common html}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/settings/basic" component={Basic} />
        <Route exact path="/settings/notifications" component={Notifications} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, with the relative from the parent, I am not able to get the same structure, I am also confused about how to get the routes split into separate files not even talking about the regex situation that I am guessing the solution is to duplicate the lines as many times as I have items in that regex...

Comment: Where is the "relative" part of any of the paths you are showing here? Also, this is all `react-router-dom@5` code. Where is the v6 code since that is what it seems you are asking about?

Comment: I don't know how to convert this into the v6, since now with all the routes being relative to the parent, if I simply change `Switch` with `Routes` and duplicate the lines with regex, I ended up not having a `/main` url working

Comment: I can help with the conversion part, but I'm not understanding this "since now with all the routes being relative to the parent" part, what you mean by that. None of the routes you are showing are relative to anything other than root since they are all absolute paths.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but from what I see in the doc (e.g. https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#:~:text=This%20is%20the%20same%20app%20in%20v6%3A)  The route on App is "users/*" and the one on `Users` is relative to that, so we declare only `:id`, but in my case is doesn't work, because I would end up with (e.g. `/main/main`)

Comment: I see. RRDv6 is capable of using both relative and absolute paths. I'll write up a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically 2 options when it comes to declaring the routes and sharing common UI:

1. Use layout routes and ***nested*** `Route` components.
2. Render routed components that render ***descendent*** routes in another `Routes` component wrapping descendent `Route` components.

### Using layout and nested routes

Convert `AuthenticatedUser` into a layout route. Layout routes render an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their matched element into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function AuthenticatedUser = () => {
  {... lots of common code}
  return (
    <div>
      {...common html}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Convert `Settings` also into a layout route component.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function Settings = () => {
  {... lots of common code}
  return (
    <div>
      {...common html}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

App

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/2" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/more-info" element={<Login />} />

      <Route element={<AuthenticatedUser />}>
        <Route path="/main" element={<Main />} />

        <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />}>
          <Route
            path="basic" // "/settings/basic"
            element={<Basic />}
          />
          <Route
            path="notifications" // "/settings/notifications"
            element={<Notifications />}
          />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

### Using descendent routes

Here the parent routes need to render their route path with a trailing `"*"` wildcard matcher so descendent routes can also be matched. Descendent `Routes` components build their route paths relative to their parent `Route` path. I'd *still* suggest using `AuthenticatedUser` as a layout route for ease, otherwise you'll have a lot of code duplication since you'd need to wrap each route individually.

App

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/2" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/more-info" element={<Login />} />

      <Route element={<AuthenticatedUser />}>
        <Route path="/main" element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="/settings/*" element={<Settings />} />
        <Route path="/notifications" element={<Notifications />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Settings

```
import { Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function Settings = () => {
  {... lots of common code}
  return (
    <div>
      {...common html}
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/basic" // "/settings/basic"
          element={<Basic />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/notifications" // "/settings/notifications"
          element={<Notifications />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks SO much, that really helps, will try that. Just to double check though, both solutions you shown uses a single file to describe all routes, this is now required? We cannot do it the same way we had before with routes being described on each file?

Comment: @Gabrielle Not at all. The second example shows the `Settings` component rendering its own descendent routes, i.e. the `Routes` component rendering `Route` components. These are declared in the root `Routes` component.